# I can't simplify this A’B’C + A’BC + A’BC’ + AB’C + ABC boolean expression to A'B+C

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have to get this expression A’B’C + A’BC + A’BC’ + AB’C + ABC to A'B+C. I did this but I can't finish it, I don't know how to.

A’B’C + A’BC + A’BC’ + AB’C + ABC

A'B(C+C')+C(A'B'+AB'+AB)

A'B+C(A'B'+AB'+AB)

That's it, I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this super-weird [absorption laws in boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws): $X+XY = X$ and $X(X+Y) = X$.

From your last line, as you "prematurely grouped" the $A'BC$ term into $A'B$, the absorption law can "recreate" an $A'BC$ out of $A'B$:

$$\begin{align*}
p &= A'B+C(A'B'+AB'+AB)\\
&= (A'B + A'BC) + C(A'B ' + AB' + AB)\\
&= A'B + C(A'B + A'B' + AB' + AB)\\
&= A'B + C(A' + A)(B'+B)\\
&= A'B + C
\end{align*}$$

Also try using Karnaugh map which helps a lot.

Comment: i liked this way better than the other, yeah i know Karnaugh but i have to solve the expression both ways, thats how i knew i had to get A'B+C, thank you

Comment: @MicaB If you draw the Karnaugh map, you should see that the rectangles corresponding to $A'B$ and $C$ covers $A'BC$ twice. So $A'BC$ is a term that should appear twice.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
E&=A'B+C(A'B'+AB'+AB)\\&=A'B+C((A'+A)B'+AB)\\ &=A'B+C(B'+AB)
\end{align}

For boolean expressions $+$ also distributes over product, by example:
$$
B'+AB = (B'+A)(B'+B)=B'+A
$$
thus

\begin{align}
E &=A'B+C(B'+A)\\ 
&=A'B+CB'+CA \\
&=(A'B+C)(A'B+B')+CA \\
&=(A'B+C)(A'+B')+CA\\
&=A'B+CA'+CB'+CA \\
&=A'B+C+CB' \\
&=A'B+C
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, im so lost though, what happened from here                                           
(A′B+C)(A′B+B′)+CA=(A′B+C)(A′+B′)+CA=A′B+CA′+CB′+CA=A′B+C+CB′=A′B+C

Answer (score 0):

Terms can be duplicated in boolean algebra, because or and and are idempotent: $X = X+X$ and $X = XX$.

$$\begin{align*}
p &= A’B’C + \underline {A’BC} + A’BC’ + AB’C + ABC\\
&= (\underline {A’BC} + A'BC') + (A'B'C + \underline {A’BC} + AB'C + ABC)\\
&= A'B(C+C') + (A'+A)(B'+B)C\\
&= A'B + C
\end{align*}$$

(Underlined terms were duplicated, no special meaning otherwise)

Also try using Karnaugh map which helps a lot.

Comment: This way looks so much easier, thank you, i might solve this problem this way

Answer (score 0):

$$A'B'C'+A'BC'+A'BC+ABC=$$

$$=A'C(B'+B)+A'BC+ABC'   , \{B'+B=1\}$$

$$=A'C'+B(A'C+AC')$$

$$=A'C' +B$$